# How to prevent Bluetooth Disconnected when moving Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bluetooth

I make a POS in android. I want to make a printing in my apps. To do printing I'm using bluetooth printer. Then, I had success make the bluetooth connection and I make it in one fragment. But every time I move to another fragment the bluetooth connction will be disconnected. How can I prevent bluetooth disconnect when moving fragment?

SettingFragment.Java

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
    public static final int MESSAGE_CONNECTION_LOST = 6;
    public static final int MESSAGE_UNABLE_CONNECT = 7;

    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    // Key names received from the BluetoothService Handler
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";

    // Intent request codes
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothService mService = null;

    private static final String CHINESE = "GBK";

    SessionManagement sessionManagement;
    DatabaseHandler db;

    TextView tvConnected;
    Button btnScan;
    Button btnTest;


    public SettingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Setting");

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        btnScan = (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
        btnTest = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
        tvConnected = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tvPrinterConnect);

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the session
        } else {
            if (mService == null)
                KeyListenerInit();
        }

        return rootview;
    }


    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    if (DEBUG)
                        Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            //btnScan.setText(getText(R.string.Connecting));
                            btnScan.setEnabled(false);
                            break;
                        case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            Toast.makeText((MainActivity)getContext(),R.string.title_connecting,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case BluetoothService.STATE_LISTEN:
                        case BluetoothService.STATE_NONE:
                            Toast.makeText((MainActivity)getContext(),R.string.title_not_connected,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:

                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:

                    break;
                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    // save the connected device's name
                    mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Connected to " + mConnectedDeviceName,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tvConnected.setText("Connected to "+mConnectedDeviceName );
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            msg.getData().getString(TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_CONNECTION_LOST:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Device connection was lost",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tvConnected.setText("Not Connect to Any Device");
//                    editText.setEnabled(false);
//                    sendButton.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_UNABLE_CONNECT:
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to connect device",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // If Bluetooth is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the session
        } else {
            if (mService == null)
                KeyListenerInit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mService != null) {

            if (mService.getState() == BluetoothService.STATE_NONE) {
                // Start the Bluetooth services
                mService.start();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop the Bluetooth services
        if (mService != null)
            mService.stop();
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:{
                // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Get the device MAC address
                    String address = data.getExtras().getString(
                            DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                    // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
                    if (BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(address)) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
                                .getRemoteDevice(address);
                        // Attempt to connect to the device
                        mService.connect(device);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:{
                // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a session
                    KeyListenerInit();
                } else {
                    // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
                    Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void KeyListenerInit() {

        btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
            }
        });

        mService = new BluetoothService(getActivity(), mHandler);
    }

}
```

BluetoothService.JAVA

```
public class BluetoothService {
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothService";
private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

// Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
private static final String NAME = "ZJPrinter";
//UUID must be this
// Unique UUID for this application
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");        

// Member fields
private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private Handler mHandler;
private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

public static String ErrorMessage = "No_Error_Message";
/**
 * Constructor. Prepares a new BTPrinter session.
 * @param context  The UI Activity Context
 * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
 */
public BluetoothService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}


/**
 * Set the current state of the connection
 * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
 */
private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(SettingFragment.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}

/**
 * Return the current connection state. */
public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

/**
 * Start the service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
 * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
public synchronized void start() {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mAcceptThread == null) {
        mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mAcceptThread.start();
    }
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
 * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
 */
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
 * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
 * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
 */
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "connected");

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(SettingFragment.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(SettingFragment.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

/**
 * Stop all threads
 */
public synchronized void stop() {
    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "stop");
    setState(STATE_NONE);
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 * @param out The bytes to write
 * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
 */
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    r.write(out);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionFailed() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(SettingFragment.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(SettingFragment.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionLost() {
    //setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(SettingFragment.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(SettingFragment.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

/**
 * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
 * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
 * (or until cancelled).
 */
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
 * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
 * succeeds or fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BluetoothService.this.start();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                if(bytes>0)
                {
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(SettingFragment.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected");
                    connectionLost();
                    
                    //add by chongqing jinou
                    if(mState != STATE_NONE)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "disconnected");
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                        BluetoothService.this.start();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                
                //add by chongqing jinou
                if(mState != STATE_NONE)
                {
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothService.this.start();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * @param buffer  The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);
            mmOutStream.flush();//清空缓存
           /* if (buffer.length > 3000) //
            {
              byte[] readata = new byte[1];
              SPPReadTimeout(readata, 1, 5000);
            }*/
            Log.i("BTPWRITE", new String(buffer,"GBK"));
            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(SettingFragment.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Make Bluetooth connectivity in Activity instead of Fragment.

Comment: but i want to make setting the connection and display it in fragment @HiteshGehlot

Comment: so what you can access fragment methods in activity and vice versa.

Comment: If `onDestroy()` gets called, your service will stop. @HiteshGehlot is right, you need to manage it outside the Fragment and then pass the data to it.

Comment: i had move it to mainActivity but now, everytime i move to another fragments, mService always detect null
Here i post another question with the new problem, pleas check it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261428/bluetooth-printer-connection-failed-in-android
Thanks @HiteshGehlot

Comment: i had move it to mainActivity but now, everytime i move to another fragments, mService always detect null
Here i post another question with the new problem, pleas check it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261428/bluetooth-printer-connection-failed-in-android
Thanks @JorgeMartín

Comment: or can u give me an example plis, cauze i super confused now @HiteshGehlot

Comment: or can u give me an example plis, cauze i super confused now @JorgeMartín